# How to get the difference value from table - django?

Tags: django

I am new to Django and came up with a problem. I have a table like

```
TABLE
Id      Title     Type   Value
1       A         1      10
2       A         1      20
3       A         2      5
4       A         2      8 
5       B         1      1000
```

Model

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company             = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value               = models.IntegerField() 
    type                = models.SmallIntegerField(default='1')
    date                = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now from the above table how can I get a value where I sum the value of a similar type and subtract the value from the different type **((A+A)-(A+A)) = 17)**. Also, I have a value of two types only.

How can I write the query to get the result.

Comment: So you want to subtract the sum of the `Value`s with `type=2` from the sum of the `Value`s with `type=1`?

Comment: Can you please share the models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I want to add all the value of value field having similar type and subtract  sum of Type 1 from  sum of Type 2. I have edited further to make it easy to understand. Thankyou

Comment: can you share the corresponding model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have added model above

Comment: do you want to extecute only one query ? if you can execute 2 queries then it is possible @nasor

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you for the answer, but I have edited the table a little more above. Can you please look at it and tell me what I need to do.

Comment: @nasor In Stack Overflow it is frowned upon if you [keep changing your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) in terms of requirements.

Comment: @nasor: what is the `title` in the table in your `model`? It looks like there is no corresponding field for that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for your answer, I added a filter for the title to the answer you provided and it worksed fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can aggregate over the model with:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Company.objects.aggregate(
    total=(Coalesce(Sum('value', filter=Q(type=1)), Value(0)) -
              Coalesce(Sum('value', filter=Q(type=2)), Value(0)))
)['total']
```